# Serving a downloadable file from a restful WCF call

Tags: wcf, jquery

I need to initiate a file download from a restful wcf service, with and am running into a few issues.

If I set up my restful call as a GET (the GET call is identical to the below with the parameters removed and the name changed), I can point a browser to it, and get a method with a correct response and my browser prompts me to download the file, however when the file is received it is empty and my headers are showing a content-length of 0.  As a note stepping through the service call, the stream is correct.

If I set up as POST and call it as an ajax call with JQuery (this is the end result I am hoping for as I need to pass some data to the service, if necessary I can pass the data points in the URL and use GET).

My questions:

1. Am I missing something to return a stream over a webHttpBinding (code below) that would cause my content to not actually be returned?
2. Is it possible to redirect an ajax response received in jquery in a way that the browser will recognize a downloadable content type, or does this have to use GET?

Service Code:

```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UtilizationReport", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Stream DownloadUtilizationReport(string startDate, string endDate)
        {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
                DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
                .
                .    
                .

                Stream stream = reportGenerator.GenerateUtilizationReport(exams);

                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv";
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MediaImport_Utilization_" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ".csv");
                return stream;


        }
```

Endpoint Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="reportDownload" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>         
      <service name="Poiesis.MediaImport.ReportingService">
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="reportDownload" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
          name="restEndpoint" contract="Poiesis.MediaImport.IReportingService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Response Received from POST:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/csv
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MediaImport_Performance2000-01-01-2012-01-01.csv
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 15:32:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Any luck yet? I get the same trying to do this, I had to change to CreateTextResponse rather than CreateStreamResponse

Comment: No, I couldn't get it working in time so I ended up just throwing up an asp page to redirect to and offer the file for download.  I little clunkier than I'd like but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As you're stepping through the service call, please confirm that the position in the stream is set to 0; if your `GenerateUtilizationReport` method is writing to the stream, but not resetting the position of the stream to start, when WCF starts reading from it, it will not find anything else. If this is a `MemoryStream`, simply set its `Position` property to 0 prior to returning it.

Comment: I had already tried that, but with stream.Seek(0,0), I just tried setting the position to 0 as well.  Neither has any affect.

Comment: Try stream.Position = 0; stream.Flush();

Answer (score 0):

Make it a GET request and set window.location to the service url.This will "trick" the browser and it will start the download.